# Unable to return value from async method

Tags: javascript

I need to fetch some Network logs from some async javascript methods, 
so I wrote below script and it returned the expected value when executed on browser console.

```
var str=null;
async function ensureFooIsSet() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        waitForFoo(resolve);
    });
}

async function waitForFoo(resolve) {
    HAR.triggerExport().then(harLog => {
        str=harLog;
        resolve();
    });
};
await ensureFooIsSet().then();
str;
```

Now I have to get value returned by str variable in my java program, for that I have to run the above script using JavaScriptExecutor, for the str to return value in javaScriptExecutor I have to change the last line of code to `return str;`

Now I am getting error "Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function"

Comment: `await ensureFooIsSet().then();` is redundant. Use either `await` or `.then()`. Since you are using it at top level in your code, I suggest using `.then`

Comment: Use https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeAsyncScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...- - don't try to muck about with `async` and `await`.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) is supported in the chrome console without wrapping it in an async function, which explains why your code was working in the console.

However, out of the console, the keywork `await` must always be used within a function marked `async`.

When you are at the top of your program, you must use `then` instead of `await`, or wrap everything into an `async` function and call it (IIFE pattern - immediately invoked function expression):

```
(aysnc function() {
    // do work
    const val = await something();
    // do something with val
})();

// OR

something().then(val => { // do something with val });
```

However, do not mix `await` and `then` as this is redundant. Just assign the value returned by your awaited function to a variable:

```
const val = await something();
```

Or use `then` to access it:

```
something().then(val => { // do something });
```